# Regex / Setting to much dots between lowercase and uppercase Words

Tags: regex, preg-replace

i have some trouble with a Regex, the purpose of this script is to do a Auto Corrrection of some Words

Example which he should Match and Replace are:

```
Word.Word
```

To: Word. Word

```
wordWord
```

To: word. Word

I do this with the following script

```
function filter_string($string) {
    $string = preg_replace("/([a-z])([A-Z])/", "$1. $2", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/([a-z]).([A-Z])/", "$1. $2", $string);
    $string = str_replace("...", "&hellip", $string);
    $string = str_replace("Games. Com", "GamesCom", $string);
    $string = str_replace("Pv. P", "PvP", $string);
    $string = str_replace("Pv. E", "PvE", $string);
    $string = str_replace("Blizz. Con", "BlizzCon", $string);
    $string = str_replace(". PvP", " PvP", $string);
    $string = str_replace(". PvE", " PvE", $string);
    return $string;
```

But for some reason he is matching also

```
Legendary Pictures zeigt uns das offizielle Poster zum Warcraft Film.
```

And replace it to

```
Legendary. Pictures zeigt uns das offizielle. Poster zum. Warcraft. Film.
```

I don't get where all the dots are coming from and why he is Matching this, i hope that someone could give me a hint whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your second regex:

```
$string = preg_replace("/([a-z]).([A-Z])/", "$1. $2", $string);
```

with this one:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\.(\w)/", ". $1", $string);
```

You probably forgot to escape the dot (its a token for any character).

Comment: Oh thank you this might be the reason =O. I tried to escape it the dots are gone, but now he wont change wordWord to "word. Word" he is yust making "word Word", hmm but you gave me a huge hint to solve this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try whitout dot space

```
$string = preg_replace("/([a-z])([A-Z])/", "$1.$2", $string); 

$string = preg_replace("/([a-z]).([A-Z])/", "$1.$2", $string);
```

Comment: Hi i tried this, but that didnt change anything. I think the part with the bug is   `$string = preg_replace("/([a-z]).([A-Z])/", "$1. $2", $string);` Normaly it should match on "word.Word" but instead its matching on other things Hmm

Comment: Try $string = preg_replace("/([a-z]/)./([A-Z]/)", "$1.$2", $string); i'm not sure, but could work..